# Store username with backslash in credential manager

Tags: windows-8-preview, credentials-manager

How can I trick credential manager to store a username that starts with a bacskslash?

Comment: why not just add the computername or the domain before it?

Comment: here's the problem... for some reason the remote server accessible only if I put backslash in front of username...

Comment: What OS/application/resource is the remote server running?

Comment: if you are using a local account on the machine type the computer name the backslash then the username.